# How can I write unit tests for Gradle plugin tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am not sure how to write unit tests for gradle plugin tasks. I cannot initialize the task directly, it will result into

```
Task of type '' has been instantiated directly which is not supported. Tasks can only be created using the DSL.
```

Comment: Try: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ProjectBuilder](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testfixtures/ProjectBuilder.html) or [TestKit](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html) to test gradle tasks

As I understand, `ProjectBuilder` is lightweight and doesn't start the whole Gradle environment and stubs/mocks out some functionality so may be limited. `TestKit` on the other hand starts a proper Gradle daemon, it's slower but can fully test anything.